# Select Adjacent class

Tags: jquery

My jQuery code is like below

```
$("#sub_"+id > '.subcat_li').addClass("active_category");
```

Here I am trying to select Adjacent `.subcat_li` Class of `"#sub_"+id`.

But it is not working.

Comment: You have `$(false)`. You have "string" Greater Than "string"

Comment: Do `$("#sub_"+id+" > .subcat_li
")..`